# What is causing two html elements with identical computed styles to vary in their display?

Tags: html, css

I have two versions of a web page, each of which is loaded in a separate tab in the same instance of chrome.

I have an h1 tag that is displaying slightly differently on each version - one displays as if it was `font-weight: 300;` and the other `font-weight: 400;`, despite the fact that dumping the full, computed style of each and diffing them together produces no relevant diff! How can this be?

Here's the diff:

```
@@ -79 +79 @@
--webkit-locale: auto;
+-webkit-locale: en;
@@ -101 +101 @@
--webkit-perspective-origin: 60.25px 18px;
+-webkit-perspective-origin: 56.453125px 18px;
@@ -117 +117 @@
--webkit-transform-origin: 60.25px 18px;
+-webkit-transform-origin: 56.453125px 18px;
@@ -248 +248 @@
-text-align: center;
+text-align: start;
@@ -267 +267 @@
-width: 120.515625px;
+width: 112.921875px;
```

Note that there is no difference in the font-weight. And I assume that the difference in width can be explained by the difference in font-weight, as opposed to causing the difference. **So why is one displaying as bolder than the other?**

edit:
The html is simple:

```
<div class="logo float-left">
    <a href="#top">
        <h1>TEXTHERE.<span>ly</span></h1>
    </a>
</div>
```

And I've included the -only- differing computed css above.

Comment: Actually providing HTML and CSS may be helpful.

Comment: They're both also subject to a transform with different origins, which might result in one being thicker.

Comment: do you set the font-weight differently or not? (you claim both)

Comment: The font-weights are computed as the same; but they display as if they were different.

Comment: Try rounding your pixel values and see if that makes a difference. How browsers render fonts is really really complicated, so each pixel makes a difference.

Comment: Is everything **exactly** the same on each page? Or is content switched up with the same structure?

Comment: More on -webkit-locale at stackoverflow.com/a/77702242/2344083

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out this was the relevant difference between the two pages:

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans);
```

which fetches this stylesheet

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Open Sans'), local('OpenSans'), url(http://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/opensans/v6/cJZKeOuBrn4kERxqtaUH3bO3LdcAZYWl9Si6vvxL-qU.woff) format('woff');
}
```

and

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato|Open+Sans:400,300);
```

which fetches this one

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Lato';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Lato Regular'), local('Lato-Regular'), url(http://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/lato/v6/qIIYRU-oROkIk8vfvxw6QvesZW2xOQ-xsNqO47m55DA.woff) format('woff');
}
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 300;
  src: local('Open Sans Light'), local('OpenSans-Light'), url(http://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/opensans/v6/DXI1ORHCpsQm3Vp6mXoaTaRDOzjiPcYnFooOUGCOsRk.woff) format('woff');
}
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Open Sans'), local('OpenSans'), url(http://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/opensans/v6/cJZKeOuBrn4kERxqtaUH3bO3LdcAZYWl9Si6vvxL-qU.woff) format('woff');
}
```

I still don't understand why the computed styles in Chrome and Firefox inspectors were coming out the same.